# How to obtain current instance ID from boto3?

Tags: python, boto3

Is there an equivalent of

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

with boto3 to obtain the current running instance instance-id in python?

Comment: The examples given in the boto3 docs use `instance_id = sys.argv[2]`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no api for it, no. There is [`InstanceMetadataFetcher`](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/utils.py#L157), but it is currently only used to fetch IAM roles for authentication.

Any sort of `GET` should serve you though. Botocore uses the python [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library which is quite nice.

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id')
instance_id = response.text
```

Comment: I accept this as the answer, but it makes no sense. How can an instance not easily know its own name?

Comment: Note: I have seen this intermittently fail (on the same instance) with `IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 113] No route to host`, so it might be best practice to try a few times.

Comment: @PatrickCollins I think it does make sense. Boto is about communicating with the AWS API and not with the local resource the request orignates from.

Answer (score 11):

In fact, scrap that answer.  All you need is `ec2-metadata` https://github.com/adamchainz/ec2-metadata

```
pip3 install ec2-metadata
```

```
from ec2_metadata import ec2_metadata
print(ec2_metadata.instance_id)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice solution. I used to call `ec2-metadata --instance-id | cut -d " " -f 2` in a subprocess before, but your answer is much better.

Answer (score 4):

There is still no boto3 api to do it. But if your current instance is Linux system, then you can use the following python3 code to get the instance_id:

```
import subprocess

cmd='''set -o pipefail && sudo grep instance-id /run/cloud-init/instance-data.json | head -1 | sed 's/.*\"i-/i-/g' | sed 's/\",//g\''''    
status, instance_id = subprocess.getstatusoutput(cmd)
print(status, instance_id)
```

Comment: I upvoted because I didn't know about instance-data.json, but running Python and then using subprocess is bit silly. Why not just do `import json; print(json.load(open("/run/cloud-init/instance-data.json"))["v1"]["instance_id"])` ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm late to the party but after coming across this question and being disappointed that there was no satisfactory boto3 based answer to getting current ec2's instanceid, I set out to fix that.

You get the hostname (which is also the PrivateDnsName) using socket and feed that into a filter on a query to describe_instances and used that to fetch the InstanceId.

```
import socket
import boto3


session = boto3.Session(region_name="eu-west-1")
ec2_client = session.client('ec2')

hostname = socket.gethostname()

filters = [ {'Name': 'private-dns-name',
            'Values': [ hostname ]}
           ]

response = ec2_client.describe_instances(Filters=filters)["Reservations"]
instanceid = response[0]['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
print(instanceid)
```

Your instance will need EC2 read privileges granted via IAM. Policy AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess granted to your instance role would work for that.